# Disassembly of a Python program using SymPy's solve function (what's going on behind the scenes?)

Tags: python, sympy

I have this Python code which solves a 3 variable linear equation.

```
import numpy as np

from sympy import *

init_printing(use_latex='mathjax')

A = Matrix([[-2,3,-1],[2,2,3],[-4,-1,1]])

x,y,z= symbols('x,y,z')
In[12]:

X =Matrix([[x],[y],[z]])

B = Matrix([[1],[1],[1]])

solve(A*X-B)
```

[image: snapshot of python program]

I am happy as well as baffled with that output. I want to understand what steps sympy follows to solve this, and what solver it's using?

Part 1 of the question is **How is sympy solving `AX-B` above?**

Part 2: In general is there a *method* to see the disassembly for any python program (for the purpose of understanding it)?

Comment: You can `import dis`, then call `dis.dis(solve)` but this will give you [disassembled bytecode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html), not sure that's exactly what you're asking for. In fact I just did so and `dis.dis(sympy.solve)` results in a ~2k line disassembly dump. You can also look at [`dis.show_code(sympy.solve)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.show_code)

Comment: Disassembling is a solution, when you doesn't have access to the source code, but SymPy is [Open Source](https://github.com/sympy/sympy)

Comment: @soon Thats partially true. Disassembly (also) comes handy when (cross)checking compiler optimization level effects. In cases where one can make programs faster by writing in-line assembly, disassembly makes the implementation visible. However, I get your point that I should look at the source of `sympy`. Thanks.

Comment: @CoryKramer It seems `dis.show_code()` is available in python >= 3.2 I'm using 2.7 . The disassembly dump created by `dis.dis()` is too low level. I will try with a higher(newer) version of python. Thanks.

Comment: Don't literally disassemble it with dis. That's way too low level to understand the algorithm of a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two basic methods:

**Read the source**

The best way to understand it is to read the source. In IPython, you can type `solve??` and it will show you the source code, as well as what file that source is in. You can also look at the [SymPy GitHub](https://github.com/sympy/sympy).

`solve` in SymPy is a bit complicated, because it can solve many different types of equations. I believe in this case, you want to look at [`solve_linear_system`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/1403bcb511def74d90178ff0f1d83f4412bc1096/sympy/solvers/solvers.py#L2103), which uses row reduction. That will be replaced with [`linsolve`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/1403bcb511def74d90178ff0f1d83f4412bc1096/sympy/solvers/solveset.py#L1085) in a future version, which uses essentially the same algorithm (Gauss-Jordan elimination).

**Use a visual debugger**

Another way to understand what is going on is to step through the code in a visual debugger. I recommend a debugger that can show you the code of the function that is being run, as well as a list of the variable, along with their values (pdb is not a great debugger in this respect). I personally prefer PuDB, which runs in the terminal, but there are other good ones as well. The advantage of using a debugger is that you can see exactly what code paths are being traversed and what values the variables have at each step.